# How to print an image in a new layout

Tags: android, image, image-processing

i tried to print a image in a new layout but it doesn't work
someone can help me?

here the code:

in mainActivity:

```
case R.id.gallery: //in the moment that the user pressed the button pickAPic, the app will give him to choose a picture
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));

                Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); //the app ask access for the gallery
                startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent, REQUEST_PICK_PIC); // when he press on a pic
                break;
```

in main2activity:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PICK_PIC:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri imageUri = intent.getData();
                Bitmap bitmap;
                try {

                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap); // the app "prints" the image that the user choose
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;

    }
}
```

so what is my problem?

thanks you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start your main2activity after handle the onActivityResult from your mainActivity like :

mainActivity:

```
case R.id.gallery: //in the moment that the user pressed the button pickAPic, the app will give him to choose a picture

    Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); //the app ask access for the gallery
    startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent, REQUEST_PICK_PIC); // when he press on a pic
    break;

...

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PICK_PIC:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri imageUri = intent.getData();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("IMAGE_URI", uri.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            break;

    }
}
```

in main2activity:

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ...
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGE_URI"));
            Bitmap bitmap;
                try {

                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap); // the app "prints" the image that the user choose
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
```

Comment: cause in the main activity i have "to choose from gallery" and i want that the main2activity will print the image

Comment: Ok, so you can handle the "onActivityResult" to get the selected image in your mainActivity and start the "main2activity" after (with the selected image in the Intent you pass to the startActivity method). It's better because you can handle the case when the user don't select an image (by tapping on Back button), and I think you don't want to start main2activity in this case ? Do you need code example ?